TOC menu doesn't collapse when hosting _build/html on a webserver
When I build and open my jupyter book locally the menu's collapse/expand as expected.
However, when I deploy _build/html as a website, e.g.
docker run -d --rm --name jupyterbook -p 8080:80 -v "$PWD/_build/html":/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/ httpd:2.4

... then menus don't collapse:

My versions:
$ jupyter-book --version
Jupyter Book      : 1.0.2
External ToC      : 1.0.1
MyST-Parser       : 2.0.0
MyST-NB           : 1.1.2
Sphinx Book Theme : 1.1.3
Jupyter-Cache     : 1.0.0
NbClient          : 0.10.0

I've looked through the issues on GitHub but haven't found anything relevant.
